# Data Requirements

Tags: database

When it is required to list and present a data dictionary for an application before the programming has even begun. What is the best approach to take in figuring out the data fields you will need for the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i have garnered through exploring my various options is a mixture of wire framing and researching the various data requirements for the various details of your system. For instance the different fields that may be needed in a table for a shelter location to be displayed on a map. Wire framing helps as you will be able to see the features of your website and combined with use cases one can acquire most of the data requirements they may need.